# How to go about learning to program in Tex?

Tags: tex-core, templates, package-writing

I have been using Tex for a few years now and enjoyed the work of others (e.g., ctan packages, templates, styles). My question sees to **practical code to learn from**. What would be a good primer, or project to study? For example I looked at ClassicThesis.sty. In order to actively contribute I would like to know how to go about.

Comment: Some great resources can be found at [Where do I start LaTeX programming?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12668)

Comment: @HenriMenke This is not right question. Better one is: where do I start __TeX__ programming?

Comment: @wipet True, the question title is different.  Christian's answer in turn addresses mostly TeX programming, e.g. in form of his primer on TeX programming.